# GraphicsRow messes up label positions of 3d plots

Tags: plotting

I want to have a few plots in a row. Two of these plots are 3d plots, and one is a 2d plot.
The problem is that once I do `GraphicsRow` the tick labels of the plot are put in new locations which do not make sense with the view I set.

Here is a minimal example:

```
ptest = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
  ViewAngle -> Automatic, ViewCenter -> {0.5`, 0.5`, 0.5`}, 
  ViewMatrix -> Automatic, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.9521414722227757`, -1.2900948113785387`, 
    1.0346574822792727`}, ViewProjection -> Automatic, 
  ViewRange -> All, ViewVector -> Automatic, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.2801838803175893`, 0.12244120873972492`, 
    0.9521056367927531`}]
```

Gives the following results:
[image]

But this messes the labels:

```
GraphicsRow[{ptest}]
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `AxesEdge` to fix the position:

```
ptest = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
  ViewAngle -> Automatic, ViewCenter -> {0.5`, 0.5`, 0.5`}, 
  ViewMatrix -> Automatic, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.9521414722227757`, -1.2900948113785387`, 
    1.0346574822792727`}, ViewProjection -> Automatic, 
  ViewRange -> All, ViewVector -> Automatic, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.2801838803175893`, 0.12244120873972492`, 
    0.9521056367927531`},
  AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}];

GraphicsRow[{ptest}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I don't have the OP's font family....